# Python 3.7: I want to pass the whole class as variable, how to use type hint to indicate the variable is a class?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

Example code:

```
def __init__(self, input_retailer, pull_gen_fun, login_class: typing.ClassVar):
    self.input_retailer = input_retailer
    self.pull_gen_fun = pull_gen_fun
    self.login_class = login_class
```

I think typing.ClassVar isn't for this kind of case correct?

Comment: Why not use `type`? All* class objects are subclasses of the builtin `type`. (*ingoring metaclass usage)

Answer (score 1):

In general, all class objects in Python are subclasses of the builtin [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

```
class T:
    pass

print(type(T))              # outputs "<class 'type'>
print(isinstance(T, type))  # outputs "True"
```

If you want to accept essentially any class object for `login_class`, annotating it using `type` is the way to go:

```
def __init__(self, input_retailer, pull_gen_fun, login_class: type):
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check this. This is what you want?

```
from typing import ClassVar


def __init__(self, input_retailer, pull_gen_fun, login_class: ClassVar):
    self.input_retailer = input_retailer
    self.pull_gen_fun = pull_gen_fun
    self.login_class = login_class
```

Comment: You still use `ClassVar`. How does this differ from the OP's solution?

Comment: OP's is trying to use **typing.ClassVar** which through error. He should import.

Comment: You misinterpret the OP's question. Their issue has nothing to do with a `NameError`. They are asking what type hint is appropriate for class objects, and point out the documentation for `typing.ClassVar` indicates that it isn't appropriate for this use.